# Log4cpp: Print date in UTC/GMT time zone

Tags: c++, log4cpp

I am working with log4cpp. Is there a way to print the timestamps/dates in log4cpp converted to GMT/UTC timezone ?

At the moment I use %d which currently prints out the local time, however I want this in UTC/GMT.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this old thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/log4cpp/mailman/log4cpp-devel/thread/492272AD.7020206%40malva.ua/#msg20831888), there is no support:

> ankit tandon пишет:
>
> > Hi All ,
> > Currently is there any way to print the timestamps/dates in log4cpp
> > converted to GMT/UTC timezone. I read somewhere that using "%d" prints
> > the date in UTC but we are still getting our local system (US) time.
> > Any help regarding this will be deeply appreciated.
>
> No, there is no way to print UTC time using PatternLayout. But you can  write your own appender that will print UTC timestamps/date.

That is at odds with [documentation](https://log4cplus.sourceforge.io/docs/html/classlog4cplus_1_1PatternLayout.html) claiming that %d prints UTC, and %D local time.

So I checked the code in log4cpp-1.1.3.tar.gz for the facts. It looks like it's always `localtime`:

```
std::time_t t = event.timeStamp.getSeconds();
localtime(&t, &currentTime);
```

Perhaps you could simply patch that line to use `gmtime` instead.